# How to show that $A+B=A+\overline{B}$ in topological vector space for a open set $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a topological vector space, let $A$ be a nonempty open subset of $\mathcal{X}$ and let $B$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathcal{X}$. I want show $A+B=A+\overline{B}$. I have known that $A + B \subset A + \overline{B}$ by $B \subset \overline{B}$. But how to show the opposite side? Does anyone can give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What has this to do with convex analysis?

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for comment. It actually is a homework question in convex analysis course.

Comment: My answer only holds if the topology is metrizable.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. Does there exist an alternative approach for arbitrary topological vector space?

Comment: I don't know off hand, you should unaccept my answer as people may not look if they think it has been answered.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the proof which works in arbitrary topological vector spaces.

Let $x \in A + \overline{B}$ be arbitrary. Then $x = a_0 + b_0$ for some $a_0 \in A$ and $b_0 \in B$. Now $A' := x - A$ is an open set containing $x - a_0 = b_0$. Since $b_0 \in \overline{B}$, we have $A' \cap B \neq \varnothing$. So, pick some $b \in A' \cap B$. Then $b = x - a$ for some $a \in A$, and rearranging we get $x = a + b$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ as desired.

Comment: A fantastic proof! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes that the topology is metrizable.

Suppose $x \in A+ \overline{B}$, then $x=a+b^*$ for some $a \in A, b^* \in \overline{B}$. Note that $A+ \overline{B}$ is open.
Suppose $b_n \to b^*$ with $b_n \in B$. Let $a_n = a+(b^*-b_n)$, then for sufficiently large $n$ we have $a_n \in A$. Then $a_n+b_n = a+b^*$ and
$a_n+b_n \in A+B$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I see the key is noting that $A + \overline{B}$ is also open.

Comment: This argument assumes that every point in $\overline{B}$ is the limit of a sequence of points in $B$, which is not true in general. For example, the unit sphere in $\ell_1$ is sequentially weakly closed but not weakly closed.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @copper.hat Can't you save this by replacing the sequences by nets?

Comment: Indeed, the answer never explicitly says that $(b_n)$ is a sequence, so fixing the answer to address non-sequentiality involves no editing of the post—it can be done entirely by the reader's understanding, as @QuantumSpace [points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392421/how-to-show-that-ab-a-overlineb-in-topological-vector-space-for-a-open-set#comment9185089_4392494), that $(b_n)$ is a net!

Comment: True; my comment was somewhat unfair! Apologies.

Comment: No problem, the goal is to assist the OP.